# Unable to parse google-services.json

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying my hand at creating a push notification app in ionic. I've been followin[this](https://www.djamware.com/post/5c6ccd1f80aca754f7a9d1ec/push-notification-using-ionic-4-and-firebase-cloud-messaging)g tutorial.

When I do a

> ionic cordova run android

I receive an error message :

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>     No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
>   Parsing json file: C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ionic4-push\platforms\android\app\google-services.json
>   26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date

Everything points to the google-services.json file not being there, or being corrupted. The file is indeed at that location, and I've redownloaded the file and replaced it.

I've gone one step further, and attempted to run the command (what I assume) ionic is running, in cmd :

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java.exe" "-Xmx64m"   "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew" -classpath "C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ionic4-push\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "cdvBuildDebug" "-b" "C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ionic4-push\platforms\android\build.gradle"

Can anyone point me in the direction of the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added app to firebase with **io.ionic.starter** this package name? and check your **google-services.json** file, it should contain information related to your package name. This kind of error occurs when your **google-services.json** file not contain your app information.

Hope it will helps!!

Comment: From other tutorials I have done, I am aware that the appId and app name must be consistent, but I saw nowhere to specify this, and subsequently assumed that this would be pulled from the google-services.json file. At the moment my app on firebase is named differently that io.ionic.starter, Let me create a new app on firebase with this name.

Comment: Sigh. it worked. I spent 4 hours trying to fix this, and all it took was a 20 seconds fix. Thanks, this worked!

Comment: Great. Please consider it accept and upvotes ,so it help others as well :)